# Masking image and animate the background image

Tags: css

I have a png file
[star.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3voU.png)

and want to create this masked image of another background
[masked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8LM8.png)

and i want background to animate like scale and rotate. how can i do that?
[masked image, rotated and scaled bg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4kVa.png)

The star is fixed and only the background should be changed.

what I have done so far:

```
<div class="mask"></div>

.mask {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: url(bg.jpg);
  mask-image: url(star.png);
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    transform: rotate(0deg) /* This rotates the whole star, i only want the bg.jpg to rotate. */
  }
  to {
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    transform: rotate(360deg) /* This rotates the whole star, i only want the bg.jpg to rotate. */
  }
}
```

Comment: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss3_mask-image0)  has your solution. Use the image that needs to be animated in    `.mask1`     in the example.